# How to get tomorrow's date in isoformat using datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to get tomorrow's date using the datetime module, just as you can get today's date. As far as i know, there isn't a simple function that returns the next day's date, but from googling i found that you can use timedelta to increment days.
However, i need the date to be in isoformat, just as today's date.
This is what i currently have:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' 
tomorrow = now + str(datetime.timedelta(days=1))
print(now)
print(tomorrow)
```

However, this returns the following for now and today respectively:

```
2021-04-18T11:18:30.363421Z
2021-04-18T11:18:30.363421Z1 day, 0:00:00
```

I need the next day's date to be the same format (isoformat) as today's date. Anyone know how to do this properly?

Comment: `utcnow` is ok if you're only interested in the string representation. Otherwise, note https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2019/11/utcnow.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the operations is incorrect. You can try:

```py
>>> now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
>>> tomorrow = now + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>>> now = now.isoformat() + 'Z'
>>> tomorrow = tomorrow.isoformat() + 'Z'
>>> now 
'2021-04-18T11:27:57.810303Z'
>>> tomorrow
'2021-04-19T11:27:57.810303Z'
```